# Haskell - Regex Strange behaviour

Tags: regex, haskell, haskell-platform

I am trying to use regex in haskell. but I noticed something strange. I am trying to put filter with the string which might contains one of this: sun.java, org.testng, sun.reflect, java.lang, and more
my regex for that is (sun.java|org.testng|sun.reflect|java.lang) and it works fine with the [regex validator](https://regex101.com)  but when I do it in haskell: below is the result.

**=>**

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> " org.testng.Hello.world" =~ "(sun.java|org.testng|sun.reflect|java.lang)" :: Bool
True
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> " org.testng.Hello.world" =~ "(org.testng|sun.java|sun.reflect|java.lang)" :: Bool
False
```

**=>**

```
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> " sun.java.Hello.world" =~ "(sun.java|org.testng|sun.reflect|java.lang)" :: Bool
False

Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> " sun.java.Hello.world" =~ "(org.testng|sun.java|sun.reflect|java.lang)" :: Bool
True
```

Am I doing something wrong here, since only second parameter from the regex is detected rest is giving false result.

**EDIT**

```
H:\>ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3
```

and

```
H:\>ghc-pkg list regex-posix
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2014.2.0.0\lib\package.conf.d:
    regex-posix-0.95.2

C:\Users\nixitp\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw32-7.8.3\package.conf.d:
    (no packages)
```

**EDIT2**
for the first time running this I got this warning:

```
<interactive>: warning: isalpha from msvcrt is linked instead of __imp_isalpha
```

Comment: Could not reproduce; I get `True` for all four queries. Can you list the versions of things you're using? `ghc --version` and `ghc-pkg list regex-posix` should do, though take care if you are in a cabal sandbox or similar.

Comment: Also, do you have `OverloadedStrings` turned on (or any other extensions)?

Comment: edited my question and I am  not sure what is OverloadedStrings I am new to Haskell, how do I check

Comment: If you don't know what `OverloadedStrings` is, you probably haven't got it turned on (it's off by default). I see you're running on Windows; for what it's worth, when I run your queries in ghci-7.8.3 with regex-posix-0.95.2 on Linux I get the expected `True` for all four expressions.

Comment: hmm, any idea how do I solve this issue other than switching to linux :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Haskell Wiki (https://wiki.haskell.org/Regular_expressions#regex-base):

> Executive summary: If you want a bug-free and/or portable POSIX extended regular expression library to use from Haskell, then regex-posix will not help you. You should use the regex-tdfa package instead.

Try using the tdfa regex package from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa.  If you are not familiar with installing Haskell packages (and you have cabal installed), you can get the TDFA version by doing `cabal install regex-tdfa`.